# Cross-platform alternative to Google Calendar and Office 365 synchronised across devices

Tags: calendar

It is yet another question about a calendar alternative, but it seems like everyone wants something else.

I am looking for a calendar synchronised with Outlook and mobile devices that a small business can use. I don't want the Exchange or Office 365 that takes over the entire account, and Google Calendar synchronisation seems problematic.

It does not have to be free.

Comment: First thoughts: [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/) with [Collabora Office](https://nextcloud.com/collaboraonline/) should fit? I don't know whether Outlook calendar can deal with CalDAV.

Comment: @Izzy: what a wonderful little gem!!! Exactly what I was looking for. It should be an answer though, why a comment? Their GroupWare is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Done, Vadim. I didn't do that straight away as I wasn't sure about the sync part (I'm no Windows user, so I don't know much about settings in Outlook). Glad you like it! Find the complete answer below. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining **[Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/)** with **[Collabora Office](https://nextcloud.com/collaboraonline/)** should be exactly what you're after:

- Nexcloud offers calendar and contacts storage, both can be synchronized with other devices using [CalDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV) resp. [CardDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CardDAV)
- Nextcloud also offers storage to share documents
- Collabora fits the Office part. It's a complete office package which can be used online, via the resp. Nextcloud accounts. That way each participant has its own "instance", while documents can easily be shared among users and, as the name suggests, even worked on "collaborative":

[image: Collabora]

Both Nextcloud and Collabora come for free, no license fees involved. Though of course if used by a business, it's possible to make a "service contract" with Nextcloud for "enhanced support" and more. Collabora integrates well with Nextcloud, as the second link in the first paragraph shows.